# Does anyone know if there is a complete translation table from the Masoretic numbering to the Greek numbering of the Psalms available somewhere?

Tags: psalms, septuagint, masoretic-text

I asked myself this question today and could not find anything. I have thus decided to answer my own question here.

The basic translation table (found e.g. in Wikipedia) is the following:

```
Hebrew numbering   Greek numbering
  (Masoretic)        (Septuagint)

      1–8                 1–8
      9–10                9
      11–113              10–112
      114–115             113
      116                 114–115
      117–146             116–145
      147                 146–147
      148–150             148–150
```

However this is only for the book numbers. The verse number translation is quite tricky and I did not find anything about it. I had to improvise.

Also, if someone knows of a good Biblical computing forum where this would be useful, let me know.

Comment: Is that the reason behind LXX having different verse numbering bec it was like that in the LXX copies originally? Why couldn't the editors normalize it to the traditional English bible or Mesoratic numbering???

Comment: @Michael16 This problem has been bothering everyone since the Reformation, when the translators of the KJV decided to follow the Masoretic numbering instead of the "Greek" numbering followed by the LXX, and the Vulgate. It is impossible to get rid of the old numbering because all medieval manuscripts refer to it. I am currently working on John Cassian's _Conferences_ and that is why I need it.

Comment: why couldnt the LXX editions in todays time follow the traditional English or Mesoratic numbering for the sake of ease?

Comment: What is the reason for the difference ? has anyone tried to uncover that, as to when and how the two versions started to difer?

Comment: @Michael16 Many recent editions of the LXX and the Vulgate follow the Masoretic numbering. This is fine if you just want to compare them to modern translations. However, if you want to correlate them with older texts like I am doing right now with Cassian, you still need the old numbering. BTW, if you could do some upvoting of my question and answers, that would be nice.

Comment: ok but its not even clear it is numbering of which book. Nobody understands it, it seems absurd. Which book ? Just Psalms? hyperlink the wikipedia article for details, also if you can brief the readers about the issue in the question, coz many wouldnt even know it.

Comment: @Michael16 It is mostly the book of Psalms, I think. The problem is that the old manuscripts did not indicate where the psalms started and ended. As a result, The Masoretic text and the Septuagint translation made different decisions as to where where to cut each psalm. Both have 150 psalms but they do not start and end at the same places. Thanks for the upvotes. Can you do the same with the answers?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the table, as a python variable (truncated for space reasons, see next answer):

```
g_mas_vul_translate = {
   '1-1': [1, 1],
   '1-2': [1, 2],
   '1-3': [1, 3],
   '1-4': [1, 4],
   '1-5': [1, 5],
   '1-6': [1, 6],
   '2-1': [2, 2],
   '2-2': [2, 3],
   '2-3': [2, 4],
   '2-4': [2, 5],
   '2-5': [2, 6],
   '2-6': [2, 7],
   '2-7': [2, 8],
   '2-8': [2, 9],
   '2-9': [2, 10],
   '2-10': [2, 11],
   '2-11': [2, 12],
   '2-12': [2, 13],
   '3-1': [3, 2],
   '3-2': [3, 3],
   '3-3': [3, 4],
   '3-4': [3, 5],
   '3-5': [3, 6],
   '3-6': [3, 7],
   '3-7': [3, 8],
   '3-8': [3, 9],
   '4-1': [4, 2],
   '4-2': [4, 3],
   '4-3': [4, 4],
   '4-4': [4, 5],
   '4-5': [4, 6],
   '4-6': [4, 7],
   '4-7': [4, 8],
   '4-8': [4, 9],
   '5-1': [5, 2],
   '5-2': [5, 3],
   '5-3': [5, 4],
   '5-4': [5, 5],
   '5-5': [5, 6],
   '5-6': [5, 7],
   '5-7': [5, 8],
   '5-8': [5, 9],
   '5-9': [5, 10],
   '5-10': [5, 11],
   '5-11': [5, 12],
   '5-12': [5, 13],
   '6-1': [6, 2],
   '6-2': [6, 3],
   '6-3': [6, 4],
   '6-4': [6, 5],
   '6-5': [6, 6],
   '6-6': [6, 7],
   '6-7': [6, 8],
   '6-8': [6, 9],
   '6-9': [6, 10],
   '6-10': [6, 11],
   '7-1': [7, 2],
   '7-2': [7, 3],
   '7-3': [7, 4],
   '7-4': [7, 5],
   '7-5': [7, 6],
   '7-6': [7, 7],
   '7-7': [7, 8],
   '7-8': [7, 9],
   '7-9': [7, 10],
   '7-10': [7, 11],
   '7-11': [7, 12],
   '7-12': [7, 13],
   '7-13': [7, 14],
   '7-14': [7, 15],
   '7-15': [7, 16],
   '7-16': [7, 17],
   '7-17': [7, 18],
   '8-1': [8, 2],
   '8-2': [8, 3],
   '8-3': [8, 4],
   '8-4': [8, 5],
   '8-5': [8, 6],
   '8-6': [8, 7],
   '8-7': [8, 8],
   '8-8': [8, 9],
   '8-9': [8, 10],
   '9-1': [9, 2],
   '9-2': [9, 3],
   '9-3': [9, 4],
   '9-4': [9, 5],
   '9-5': [9, 6],
   '9-6': [9, 7],
   '9-7': [9, 8],
   '9-8': [9, 9],
   '9-9': [9, 10],
   '9-10': [9, 11],
   '9-11': [9, 12],
   '9-12': [9, 13],
   '9-13': [9, 14],
   '9-14': [9, 15],
   '9-15': [9, 16],
   '9-16': [9, 17],
   '9-17': [9, 18],
   '9-18': [9, 19],
   '9-19': [9, 20],
   '9-20': [9, 21],
   '10-1': [9, 22],
   '10-2': [9, 23],
   '10-3': [9, 24],
   '10-4': [9, 25],
   '10-5': [9, 26],
   '10-6': [9, 27],
   '10-7': [9, 28],
   '10-8': [9, 29],
   '10-9': [9, 30],
   '10-10': [9, 31],
   '10-11': [9, 32],
   '10-12': [9, 33],
   '10-13': [9, 34],
   '10-14': [9, 35],
   '10-15': [9, 36],
   '10-16': [9, 37],
   '10-17': [9, 38],
   '10-18': [9, 39],
   '11-1': [10, 2],
   '11-2': [10, 3],
   '11-3': [10, 4],
   '11-4': [10, 5],
   '11-5': [10, 6],
   '11-6': [10, 7],
   '11-7': [10, 8],
   '12-1': [11, 2],
   '12-2': [11, 3],
   '12-3': [11, 4],
   '12-4': [11, 5],
   '12-5': [11, 6],
   '12-6': [11, 7],
   '12-7': [11, 8],
   '12-8': [11, 9],
   '13-1': [12, 1],
   '13-2': [12, 2],
   '13-3': [12, 3],
   '13-4': [12, 4],
   '13-5': [12, 5],
   '13-6': [12, 6],
   '14-1': [13, 1],
   '14-2': [13, 2],
   '14-3': [13, 3],
   '14-4': [13, 4],
   '14-5': [13, 5],
   '14-6': [13, 6],
   '14-7': [13, 7],
   '15-1': [14, 1],
   '15-2': [14, 2],
   '15-3': [14, 3],
   '15-4': [14, 4],
   '15-5': [14, 5],
   '16-1': [15, 1],
   '16-2': [15, 2],
   '16-3': [15, 3],
   '16-4': [15, 4],
   '16-5': [15, 5],
   '16-6': [15, 6],
   '16-7': [15, 7],
   '16-8': [15, 8],
   '16-9': [15, 9],
   '16-10': [15, 10],
   '16-11': [15, 10],
   '17-1': [16, 1],
   '17-2': [16, 2],
   '17-3': [16, 3],
   '17-4': [16, 4],
   '17-5': [16, 5],
   '17-6': [16, 6],
   '17-7': [16, 7],
   '17-8': [16, 8],
   '17-9': [16, 9],
   '17-10': [16, 10],
   '17-11': [16, 11],
   '17-12': [16, 12],
   '17-13': [16, 13],
   '17-14': [16, 14],
   '17-15': [16, 15],
   '18-1': [17, 2],
   '18-2': [17, 3],
   '18-3': [17, 4],
   '18-4': [17, 5],
   '18-5': [17, 6],
   '18-6': [17, 7],
   '18-7': [17, 8],
   '18-8': [17, 9],
   '18-9': [17, 10],
   '18-10': [17, 11],
   '18-11': [17, 12],
   '18-12': [17, 13],
   '18-13': [17, 14],
   '18-14': [17, 15],
   '18-15': [17, 16],
   '18-16': [17, 17],
   '18-17': [17, 18],
   '18-18': [17, 19],
   '18-19': [17, 20],
   '18-20': [17, 21],
   '18-21': [17, 22],
   '18-22': [17, 23],
   '18-23': [17, 24],
   '18-24': [17, 25],
   '18-25': [17, 26],
   '18-26': [17, 27],
   '18-27': [17, 28],
   '18-28': [17, 29],
   '18-29': [17, 30],
   '18-30': [17, 31],
   '18-31': [17, 32],
   '18-32': [17, 33],
   '18-33': [17, 34],
   '18-34': [17, 35],
   '18-35': [17, 36],
   '18-36': [17, 37],
   '18-37': [17, 38],
   '18-38': [17, 39],
   '18-39': [17, 40],
   '18-40': [17, 41],
   '18-41': [17, 42],
   '18-42': [17, 43],
   '18-43': [17, 44],
   '18-44': [17, 45],
   '18-45': [17, 46],
   '18-46': [17, 47],
   '18-47': [17, 48],
   '18-48': [17, 49],
   '18-49': [17, 50],
   '18-50': [17, 51],
   '19-1': [18, 2],
   '19-2': [18, 3],
   '19-3': [18, 4],
   '19-4': [18, 5],
   '19-5': [18, 6],
   '19-6': [18, 7],
   '19-7': [18, 8],
   '19-8': [18, 9],
   '19-9': [18, 10],
   '19-10': [18, 11],
   '19-11': [18, 12],
   '19-12': [18, 13],
   '19-13': [18, 14],
   '19-14': [18, 15],
   '20-1': [19, 2],
   '20-2': [19, 3],
   '20-3': [19, 4],
   '20-4': [19, 5],
   '20-5': [19, 6],
   '20-6': [19, 7],
   '20-7': [19, 8],
   '20-8': [19, 9],
   '20-9': [19, 10],
   '21-1': [20, 2],
   '21-2': [20, 3],
   '21-3': [20, 4],
   '21-4': [20, 5],
   '21-5': [20, 6],
   '21-6': [20, 7],
   '21-7': [20, 8],
   '21-8': [20, 9],
   '21-9': [20, 10],
   '21-10': [20, 11],
   '21-11': [20, 12],
   '21-12': [20, 13],
   '21-13': [20, 14],
   '22-1': [21, 2],
   '22-2': [21, 3],
   '22-3': [21, 4],
   '22-4': [21, 5],
   '22-5': [21, 6],
   '22-6': [21, 7],
   '22-7': [21, 8],
   '22-8': [21, 9],
   '22-9': [21, 10],
   '22-10': [21, 11],
   '22-11': [21, 12],
   '22-12': [21, 13],
   '22-13': [21, 14],
   '22-14': [21, 15],
   '22-15': [21, 16],
   '22-16': [21, 17],
   '22-17': [21, 18],
   '22-18': [21, 19],
   '22-19': [21, 20],
   '22-20': [21, 21],
   '22-21': [21, 22],
   '22-22': [21, 23],
   '22-23': [21, 24],
   '22-24': [21, 25],
   '22-25': [21, 26],
   '22-26': [21, 27],
   '22-27': [21, 28],
   '22-28': [21, 29],
   '22-29': [21, 30],
   '22-30': [21, 31],
   '22-31': [21, 32],
   '23-1': [22, 1],
   '23-2': [22, 2],
   '23-3': [22, 3],
   '23-4': [22, 4],
   '23-5': [22, 5],
   '23-6': [22, 6],
   '24-1': [23, 1],
   '24-2': [23, 2],
   '24-3': [23, 3],
   '24-4': [23, 4],
   '24-5': [23, 5],
   '24-6': [23, 6],
   '24-7': [23, 7],
   '24-8': [23, 8],
   '24-9': [23, 9],
   '24-10': [23, 10],
   '25-1': [24, 1],
   '25-2': [24, 2],
   '25-3': [24, 3],
   '25-4': [24, 4],
   '25-5': [24, 5],
   '25-6': [24, 6],
   '25-7': [24, 7],
   '25-8': [24, 8],
   '25-9': [24, 9],
   '25-10': [24, 10],
   '25-11': [24, 11],
   '25-12': [24, 12],
   '25-13': [24, 13],
   '25-14': [24, 14],
   '25-15': [24, 15],
   '25-16': [24, 16],
   '25-17': [24, 17],
   '25-18': [24, 18],
   '25-19': [24, 19],
   '25-20': [24, 20],
   '25-21': [24, 21],
   '25-22': [24, 22],
   '26-1': [25, 1],
   '26-2': [25, 2],
   '26-3': [25, 3],
   '26-4': [25, 4],
   '26-5': [25, 5],
   '26-6': [25, 6],
   '26-7': [25, 7],
   '26-8': [25, 8],
   '26-9': [25, 9],
   '26-10': [25, 10],
   '26-11': [25, 11],
   '26-12': [25, 12],
   '27-1': [26, 1],
   '27-2': [26, 2],
   '27-3': [26, 3],
   '27-4': [26, 4],
   '27-5': [26, 5],
   '27-6': [26, 6],
   '27-7': [26, 7],
   '27-8': [26, 8],
   '27-9': [26, 9],
   '27-10': [26, 10],
   '27-11': [26, 11],
   '27-12': [26, 12],
   '27-13': [26, 13],
   '27-14': [26, 14],
   '28-1': [27, 1],
   '28-2': [27, 2],
   '28-3': [27, 3],
   '28-4': [27, 4],
   '28-5': [27, 5],
   '28-6': [27, 6],
   '28-7': [27, 7],
   '28-8': [27, 8],
   '28-9': [27, 9],
   '29-1': [28, 1],
   '29-2': [28, 2],
   '29-3': [28, 3],
   '29-4': [28, 4],
   '29-5': [28, 5],
   '29-6': [28, 6],
   '29-7': [28, 7],
   '29-8': [28, 8],
   '29-9': [28, 9],
   '29-10': [28, 10],
   '29-11': [28, 11],
   '30-1': [29, 2],
   '30-2': [29, 3],
   '30-3': [29, 4],
   '30-4': [29, 5],
   '30-5': [29, 6],
   '30-6': [29, 7],
   '30-7': [29, 8],
   '30-8': [29, 9],
   '30-9': [29, 10],
   '30-10': [29, 11],
   '30-11': [29, 12],
   '30-12': [29, 13],
   '31-1': [30, 2],
   '31-2': [30, 3],
   '31-3': [30, 4],
   '31-4': [30, 5],
   '31-5': [30, 6],
   '31-6': [30, 7],
   '31-7': [30, 8],
   '31-8': [30, 9],
   '31-9': [30, 10],
   '31-10': [30, 11],
   '31-11': [30, 12],
   '31-12': [30, 13],
   '31-13': [30, 14],
   '31-14': [30, 15],
   '31-15': [30, 16],
   '31-16': [30, 17],
   '31-17': [30, 18],
   '31-18': [30, 19],
   '31-19': [30, 20],
   '31-20': [30, 21],
   '31-21': [30, 22],
   '31-22': [30, 23],
   '31-23': [30, 24],
   '31-24': [30, 25],
   '32-1': [31, 1],
   '32-2': [31, 2],
   '32-3': [31, 3],
   '32-4': [31, 4],
   '32-5': [31, 5],
   '32-6': [31, 6],
   '32-7': [31, 7],
   '32-8': [31, 8],
   '32-9': [31, 9],
   '32-10': [31, 10],
   '32-11': [31, 11],
   '33-1': [32, 1],
   '33-2': [32, 2],
   '33-3': [32, 3],
   '33-4': [32, 4],
   '33-5': [32, 5],
   '33-6': [32, 6],
   '33-7': [32, 7],
   '33-8': [32, 8],
   '33-9': [32, 9],
   '33-10': [32, 10],
   '33-11': [32, 11],
   '33-12': [32, 12],
   '33-13': [32, 13],
   '33-14': [32, 14],
   '33-15': [32, 15],
   '33-16': [32, 16],
   '33-17': [32, 17],
   '33-18': [32, 18],
   '33-19': [32, 19],
   '33-20': [32, 20],
   '33-21': [32, 21],
   '33-22': [32, 22],
   '34-1': [33, 2],
   '34-2': [33, 3],
   '34-3': [33, 4],
   '34-4': [33, 5],
   '34-5': [33, 6],
   '34-6': [33, 7],
   '34-7': [33, 8],
   '34-8': [33, 9],
   '34-9': [33, 10],
   '34-10': [33, 11],
   '34-11': [33, 12],
   '34-12': [33, 13],
   '34-13': [33, 14],
   '34-14': [33, 15],
   '34-15': [33, 16],
   '34-16': [33, 17],
   '34-17': [33, 18],
   '34-18': [33, 19],
   '34-19': [33, 20],
   '34-20': [33, 21],
   '34-21': [33, 22],
   '34-22': [33, 23],
   '35-1': [34, 1],
   '35-2': [34, 2],
   '35-3': [34, 3],
   '35-4': [34, 4],
   '35-5': [34, 5],
   '35-6': [34, 6],
   '35-7': [34, 7],
   '35-8': [34, 8],
   '35-9': [34, 9],
   '35-10': [34, 10],
   '35-11': [34, 11],
   '35-12': [34, 12],
   '35-13': [34, 13],
   '35-14': [34, 14],
   '35-15': [34, 15],
   '35-16': [34, 16],
   '35-17': [34, 17],
   '35-18': [34, 18],
   '35-19': [34, 19],
   '35-20': [34, 20],
   '35-21': [34, 21],
   '35-22': [34, 22],
   '35-23': [34, 23],
   '35-24': [34, 24],
   '35-25': [34, 25],
   '35-26': [34, 26],
   '35-27': [34, 27],
   '35-28': [34, 28],
   '36-1': [35, 2],
   '36-2': [35, 3],
   '36-3': [35, 4],
   '36-4': [35, 5],
   '36-5': [35, 6],
   '36-6': [35, 7],
   '36-7': [35, 8],
   '36-8': [35, 9],
   '36-9': [35, 10],
   '36-10': [35, 11],
   '36-11': [35, 12],
   '36-12': [35, 13],
   '37-1': [36, 1],
   '37-2': [36, 2],
   '37-3': [36, 3],
   '37-4': [36, 4],
   '37-5': [36, 5],
   '37-6': [36, 6],
   '37-7': [36, 7],
   '37-8': [36, 8],
   '37-9': [36, 9],
   '37-10': [36, 10],
   '37-11': [36, 11],
   '37-12': [36, 12],
   '37-13': [36, 13],
   '37-14': [36, 14],
   '37-15': [36, 15],
   '37-16': [36, 16],
   '37-17': [36, 17],
   '37-18': [36, 18],
   '37-19': [36, 19],
   '37-20': [36, 20],
   '37-21': [36, 21],
   '37-22': [36, 22],
   '37-23': [36, 23],
   '37-24': [36, 24],
   '37-25': [36, 25],
   '37-26': [36, 26],
   '37-27': [36, 27],
   '37-28': [36, 28],
   '37-29': [36, 29],
   '37-30': [36, 30],
   '37-31': [36, 31],
   '37-32': [36, 32],
   '37-33': [36, 33],
   '37-34': [36, 34],
   '37-35': [36, 35],
   '37-36': [36, 36],
   '37-37': [36, 37],
   '37-38': [36, 38],
   '37-39': [36, 39],
   '37-40': [36, 40],
   '38-1': [37, 2],
   '38-2': [37, 3],
   '38-3': [37, 4],
   '38-4': [37, 5],
   '38-5': [37, 6],
   '38-6': [37, 7],
   '38-7': [37, 8],
   '38-8': [37, 9],
   '38-9': [37, 10],
   '38-10': [37, 11],
   '38-11': [37, 12],
   '38-12': [37, 13],
   '38-13': [37, 14],
   '38-14': [37, 15],
   '38-15': [37, 16],
   '38-16': [37, 17],
   '38-17': [37, 18],
   '38-18': [37, 19],
   '38-19': [37, 20],
   '38-20': [37, 21],
   '38-21': [37, 22],
   '38-22': [37, 23],
   '39-1': [38, 2],
   '39-2': [38, 3],
   '39-3': [38, 4],
   '39-4': [38, 5],
   '39-5': [38, 6],
   '39-6': [38, 7],
   '39-7': [38, 8],
   '39-8': [38, 9],
   '39-9': [38, 10],
   '39-10': [38, 11],
   '39-11': [38, 12],
   '39-12': [38, 13],
   '39-13': [38, 14],
   '40-1': [39, 2],
   '40-2': [39, 3],
   '40-3': [39, 4],
   '40-4': [39, 5],
   '40-5': [39, 6],
   '40-6': [39, 7],
   '40-7': [39, 8],
   '40-8': [39, 9],
   '40-9': [39, 10],
   '40-10': [39, 11],
   '40-11': [39, 12],
   '40-12': [39, 13],
   '40-13': [39, 14],
   '40-14': [39, 15],
   '40-15': [39, 16],
   '40-16': [39, 17],
   '40-17': [39, 18],
   '41-1': [40, 2],
   '41-2': [40, 3],
   '41-3': [40, 4],
   '41-4': [40, 5],
   '41-5': [40, 6],
   '41-6': [40, 7],
   '41-7': [40, 8],
   '41-8': [40, 9],
   '41-9': [40, 10],
   '41-10': [40, 11],
   '41-11': [40, 12],
   '41-12': [40, 13],
   '41-13': [40, 14],
   '42-1': [41, 2],
   '42-2': [41, 3],
   '42-3': [41, 4],
   '42-4': [41, 5],
   '42-5': [41, 6],
   '42-6': [41, 7],
   '42-7': [41, 8],
   '42-8': [41, 9],
   '42-9': [41, 10],
   '42-10': [41, 11],
   '42-11': [41, 12],
   '43-1': [42, 1],
   '43-2': [42, 2],
   '43-3': [42, 3],
   '43-4': [42, 4],
   '43-5': [42, 5],
   '44-1': [43, 1],
   '44-2': [43, 2],
   '44-3': [43, 3],
   '44-4': [43, 4],
   '44-5': [43, 5],
   '44-6': [43, 6],
   '44-7': [43, 7],
   '44-8': [43, 8],
   '44-9': [43, 9],
   '44-10': [43, 10],
   '44-11': [43, 11],
   '44-12': [43, 12],
   '44-13': [43, 13],
   '44-14': [43, 14],
   '44-15': [43, 15],
   '44-16': [43, 16],
   '44-17': [43, 17],
   '44-18': [43, 18],
   '44-19': [43, 19],
   '44-20': [43, 20],
   '44-21': [43, 21],
   '44-22': [43, 22],
   '44-23': [43, 23],
   '44-24': [43, 24],
   '44-25': [43, 25],
   '44-26': [43, 26],
   '45-1': [44, 2],
   '45-2': [44, 3],
   '45-3': [44, 4],
   '45-4': [44, 5],
   '45-5': [44, 6],
   '45-6': [44, 7],
   '45-7': [44, 8],
   '45-8': [44, 9],
   '45-9': [44, 10],
   '45-10': [44, 11],
   '45-11': [44, 12],
   '45-12': [44, 13],
   '45-13': [44, 14],
   '45-14': [44, 15],
   '45-15': [44, 16],
   '45-16': [44, 17],
   '45-17': [44, 18],
   '46-1': [45, 2],
   '46-2': [45, 3],
   '46-3': [45, 4],
   '46-4': [45, 5],
   '46-5': [45, 6],
   '46-6': [45, 7],
   '46-7': [45, 8],
   '46-8': [45, 9],
   '46-9': [45, 10],
   '46-10': [45, 11],
   '46-11': [45, 12],
   '47-1': [46, 2],
   '47-2': [46, 3],
   '47-3': [46, 4],
   '47-4': [46, 5],
   '47-5': [46, 6],
   '47-6': [46, 7],
   '47-7': [46, 8],
   '47-8': [46, 9],
   '47-9': [46, 10],
   '48-1': [47, 2],
   '48-2': [47, 3],
   '48-3': [47, 4],
   '48-4': [47, 5],
   '48-5': [47, 6],
   '48-6': [47, 7],
   '48-7': [47, 8],
   '48-8': [47, 9],
   '48-9': [47, 10],
   '48-10': [47, 11],
   '48-11': [47, 12],
   '48-12': [47, 13],
   '48-13': [47, 14],
   '48-14': [47, 15],
   '49-1': [48, 2],
   '49-2': [48, 3],
   '49-3': [48, 4],
   '49-4': [48, 5],
   '49-5': [48, 6],
   '49-6': [48, 7],
   '49-7': [48, 8],
   '49-8': [48, 9],
   '49-9': [48, 10],
   '49-10': [48, 11],
   '49-11': [48, 12],
   '49-12': [48, 13],
   '49-13': [48, 14],
   '49-14': [48, 15],
   '49-15': [48, 16],
   '49-16': [48, 17],
   '49-17': [48, 18],
   '49-18': [48, 19],
   '49-19': [48, 20],
   '49-20': [48, 21],
   '50-1': [49, 1],
   '50-2': [49, 2],
   '50-3': [49, 3],
   '50-4': [49, 4],
   '50-5': [49, 5],
   '50-6': [49, 6],
   '50-7': [49, 7],
   '50-8': [49, 8],
   '50-9': [49, 9],
   '50-10': [49, 10],
   '50-11': [49, 11],
   '50-12': [49, 12],
   '50-13': [49, 13],
   '50-14': [49, 14],
   '50-15': [49, 15],
   '50-16': [49, 16],
   '50-17': [49, 17],
   '50-18': [49, 18],
   '50-19': [49, 19],
   '50-20': [49, 20],
   '50-21': [49, 21],
   '50-22': [49, 22],
   '50-23': [49, 23],
   '51-1': [50, 2],
   '51-2': [50, 3],
   '51-3': [50, 4],
   '51-4': [50, 5],
   '51-5': [50, 6],
   '51-6': [50, 7],
   '51-7': [50, 8],
   '51-8': [50, 9],
   '51-9': [50, 10],
   '51-10': [50, 11],
   '51-11': [50, 12],
   '51-12': [50, 13],
   '51-13': [50, 14],
   '51-14': [50, 15],
   '51-15': [50, 16],
   '51-16': [50, 17],
   '51-17': [50, 18],
   '51-18': [50, 19],
   '51-19': [50, 20],
   '52-1': [51, 2],
   '52-2': [51, 3],
   '52-3': [51, 4],
   '52-4': [51, 5],
   '52-5': [51, 6],
   '52-6': [51, 7],
   '52-7': [51, 8],
   '52-8': [51, 9],
   '52-9': [51, 10],
   '53-1': [52, 2],
   '53-2': [52, 3],
   '53-3': [52, 4],
   '53-4': [52, 5],
   '53-5': [52, 6],
   '53-6': [52, 7],
   '54-1': [53, 2],
   '54-2': [53, 3],
   '54-3': [53, 4],
   '54-4': [53, 5],
   '54-5': [53, 6],
   '54-6': [53, 7],
   '54-7': [53, 8],
   '55-1': [54, 2],
   '55-2': [54, 3],
   '55-3': [54, 4],
   '55-4': [54, 5],
   '55-5': [54, 6],
   '55-6': [54, 7],
   '55-7': [54, 8],
   '55-8': [54, 9],
   '55-9': [54, 10],
   '55-10': [54, 11],
   '55-11': [54, 12],
   '55-12': [54, 13],
   '55-13': [54, 14],
   '55-14': [54, 15],
   '55-15': [54, 16],
   '55-16': [54, 17],
   '55-17': [54, 18],
   '55-18': [54, 19],
   '55-19': [54, 20],
   '55-20': [54, 21],
   '55-21': [54, 22],
   '55-22': [54, 23],
   '55-23': [54, 24],
   '56-1': [55, 1],
   '56-2': [55, 2],
   '56-3': [55, 3],
   '56-4': [55, 4],
   '56-5': [55, 5],
   '56-6': [55, 6],
   '56-7': [55, 7],
   '56-8': [55, 8],
   '56-9': [55, 9],
   '56-10': [55, 10],
   '56-11': [55, 11],
   '56-12': [55, 12],
   '56-13': [55, 13],
   '57-1': [56, 2],
   '57-2': [56, 3],
   '57-3': [56, 4],
   '57-4': [56, 5],
   '57-5': [56, 6],
   '57-6': [56, 7],
   '57-7': [56, 8],
   '57-8': [56, 9],
   '57-9': [56, 10],
   '57-10': [56, 11],
   '57-11': [56, 12],
   '58-1': [57, 2],
   '58-2': [57, 3],
   '58-3': [57, 4],
   '58-4': [57, 5],
   '58-5': [57, 6],
   '58-6': [57, 7],
   '58-7': [57, 8],
   '58-8': [57, 9],
   '58-9': [57, 10],
   '58-10': [57, 11],
   '58-11': [57, 12],
   '59-1': [58, 2],
   '59-2': [58, 3],
   '59-3': [58, 4],
   '59-4': [58, 5],
   '59-5': [58, 6],
   '59-6': [58, 7],
   '59-7': [58, 8],
   '59-8': [58, 9],
   '59-9': [58, 10],
   '59-10': [58, 11],
   '59-11': [58, 12],
   '59-12': [58, 13],
   '59-13': [58, 14],
   '59-14': [58, 15],
   '59-15': [58, 16],
   '59-16': [58, 17],
   '59-17': [58, 18],
   '60-1': [59, 2],
   '60-2': [59, 3],
   '60-3': [59, 4],
   '60-4': [59, 5],
   '60-5': [59, 6],
   '60-6': [59, 7],
   '60-7': [59, 8],
   '60-8': [59, 9],
   '60-9': [59, 10],
   '60-10': [59, 11],
   '60-11': [59, 12],
   '60-12': [59, 13],
   '61-1': [60, 2],
   '61-2': [60, 3],
   '61-3': [60, 4],
   '61-4': [60, 5],
   '61-5': [60, 6],
   '61-6': [60, 7],
   '61-7': [60, 8],
   '61-8': [60, 9],
   '62-1': [61, 2],
   '62-2': [61, 3],
   '62-3': [61, 4],
   '62-4': [61, 5],
   '62-5': [61, 6],
   '62-6': [61, 7],
   '62-7': [61, 8],
   '62-8': [61, 9],
   '62-9': [61, 10],
   '62-10': [61, 11],
   '62-11': [61, 12],
   '62-12': [61, 13],
   '63-1': [62, 2],
   '63-2': [62, 3],
   '63-3': [62, 4],
   '63-4': [62, 5],
   '63-5': [62, 6],
   '63-6': [62, 7],
   '63-7': [62, 8],
   '63-8': [62, 9],
   '63-9': [62, 10],
   '63-10': [62, 11],
   '63-11': [62, 12],
   '64-1': [63, 2],
   '64-2': [63, 3],
   '64-3': [63, 4],
   '64-4': [63, 5],
   '64-5': [63, 6],
   '64-6': [63, 7],
   '64-7': [63, 8],
   '64-8': [63, 9],
   '64-9': [63, 10],
   '64-10': [63, 11],
   '65-1': [64, 2],
   '65-2': [64, 3],
   '65-3': [64, 4],
   '65-4': [64, 5],
   '65-5': [64, 6],
   '65-6': [64, 7],
   '65-7': [64, 8],
   '65-8': [64, 9],
   '65-9': [64, 10],
   '65-10': [64, 11],
   '65-11': [64, 12],
   '65-12': [64, 13],
   '65-13': [64, 14],
   '66-1': [65, 1],
   '66-2': [65, 2],
   '66-3': [65, 3],
   '66-4': [65, 4],
   '66-5': [65, 5],
   '66-6': [65, 6],
   '66-7': [65, 7],
   '66-8': [65, 8],
   '66-9': [65, 9],
   '66-10': [65, 10],
   '66-11': [65, 11],
   '66-12': [65, 12],
   '66-13': [65, 13],
   '66-14': [65, 14],
   '66-15': [65, 15],
   '66-16': [65, 16],
   '66-17': [65, 17],
   '66-18': [65, 18],
   '66-19': [65, 19],
   '66-20': [65, 20],
   '67-1': [66, 2],
   '67-2': [66, 3],
   '67-3': [66, 4],
   '67-4': [66, 5],
   '67-5': [66, 6],
   '67-6': [66, 7],
   '67-7': [66, 8],
   '68-1': [67, 2],
   '68-2': [67, 3],
   '68-3': [67, 4],
   '68-4': [67, 5],
   '68-5': [67, 6],
   '68-6': [67, 7],
   '68-7': [67, 8],
   '68-8': [67, 9],
   '68-9': [67, 10],
   '68-10': [67, 11],
   '68-11': [67, 12],
   '68-12': [67, 13],
   '68-13': [67, 14],
   '68-14': [67, 15],
   '68-15': [67, 16],
   '68-16': [67, 17],
   '68-17': [67, 18],
   '68-18': [67, 19],
   '68-19': [67, 20],
   '68-20': [67, 21],
   '68-21': [67, 22],
   '68-22': [67, 23],
   '68-23': [67, 24],
   '68-24': [67, 25],
   '68-25': [67, 26],
   '68-26': [67, 27],
   '68-27': [67, 28],
   '68-28': [67, 29],
   '68-29': [67, 30],
   '68-30': [67, 31],
   '68-31': [67, 32],
   '68-32': [67, 33],
   '68-33': [67, 34],
   '68-34': [67, 35],
   '68-35': [67, 36],
   '69-1': [68, 2],
   '69-2': [68, 3],
   '69-3': [68, 4],
   '69-4': [68, 5],
   '69-5': [68, 6],
   '69-6': [68, 7],
   '69-7': [68, 8],
   '69-8': [68, 9],
   '69-9': [68, 10],
   '69-10': [68, 11],
   '69-11': [68, 12],
   '69-12': [68, 13],
   '69-13': [68, 14],
   '69-14': [68, 15],
   '69-15': [68, 16],
   '69-16': [68, 17],
   '69-17': [68, 18],
   '69-18': [68, 19],
   '69-19': [68, 20],
   '69-20': [68, 21],
   '69-21': [68, 22],
   '69-22': [68, 23],
   '69-23': [68, 24],
   '69-24': [68, 25],
   '69-25': [68, 26],
   '69-26': [68, 27],
   '69-27': [68, 28],
   '69-28': [68, 29],
   '69-29': [68, 30],
   '69-30': [68, 31],
   '69-31': [68, 32],
   '69-32': [68, 33],
   '69-33': [68, 34],
   '69-34': [68, 35],
   '69-35': [68, 36],
   '69-36': [68, 37],
   '70-1': [69, 2],
   '70-2': [69, 3],
   '70-3': [69, 4],
   '70-4': [69, 5],
   '70-5': [69, 6],
   '71-1': [70, 1],
   '71-2': [70, 2],
   '71-3': [70, 3],
   '71-4': [70, 4],
   '71-5': [70, 5],
   '71-6': [70, 6],
   '71-7': [70, 7],
   '71-8': [70, 8],
   '71-9': [70, 9],
   '71-10': [70, 10],
   '71-11': [70, 11],
   '71-12': [70, 12],
   '71-13': [70, 13],
   '71-14': [70, 14],
   '71-15': [70, 15],
   '71-16': [70, 16],
   '71-17': [70, 17],
   '71-18': [70, 18],
   '71-19': [70, 19],
   '71-20': [70, 20],
   '71-21': [70, 21],
   '71-22': [70, 22],
   '71-23': [70, 23],
   '71-24': [70, 24],
   '72-1': [71, 1],
   '72-2': [71, 2],
   '72-3': [71, 3],
   '72-4': [71, 4],
   '72-5': [71, 5],
   '72-6': [71, 6],
   '72-7': [71, 7],
   '72-8': [71, 8],
   '72-9': [71, 9],
   '72-10': [71, 10],
   '72-11': [71, 11],
   '72-12': [71, 12],
   '72-13': [71, 13],
   '72-14': [71, 14],
   '72-15': [71, 15],
   '72-16': [71, 16],
   '72-17': [71, 17],
   '72-18': [71, 18],
   '72-19': [71, 19],
   '72-20': [71, 20],
   '73-1': [72, 1],
   '73-2': [72, 2],
   '73-3': [72, 3],
   '73-4': [72, 4],
   '73-5': [72, 5],
   '73-6': [72, 6],
   '73-7': [72, 7],
   '73-8': [72, 8],
   '73-9': [72, 9],
   '73-10': [72, 10],
   '73-11': [72, 11],
   '73-12': [72, 12],
   '73-13': [72, 13],
   '73-14': [72, 14],
   '73-15': [72, 15],
   '73-16': [72, 16],
   '73-17': [72, 17],
   '73-18': [72, 18],
   '73-19': [72, 19],
   '73-20': [72, 20],
   '73-21': [72, 21],
   '73-22': [72, 22],
   '73-23': [72, 23],
   '73-24': [72, 24],
   '73-25': [72, 25],
   '73-26': [72, 26],
   '73-27': [72, 27],
   '73-28': [72, 28],
   '74-1': [73, 1],
   '74-2': [73, 2],
   '74-3': [73, 3],
   '74-4': [73, 4],
   '74-5': [73, 5],
   '74-6': [73, 6],
   '74-7': [73, 7],
   '74-8': [73, 8],
   '74-9': [73, 9],
   '74-10': [73, 10],
   '74-11': [73, 11],
   '74-12': [73, 12],
   '74-13': [73, 13],
   '74-14': [73, 14],
   '74-15': [73, 15],
   '74-16': [73, 16],
   '74-17': [73, 17],
   '74-18': [73, 18],
   '74-19': [73, 19],
   '74-20': [73, 20],
   '74-21': [73, 21],
   '74-22': [73, 22],
   '74-23': [73, 23],
   '75-1': [74, 2],
   '75-2': [74, 3],
   '75-3': [74, 4],
   '75-4': [74, 5],
   '75-5': [74, 6],
   '75-6': [74, 7],
   '75-7': [74, 8],
   '75-8': [74, 9],
   '75-9': [74, 10],
   '75-10': [74, 11],
   '76-1': [75, 2],
   '76-2': [75, 3],
   '76-3': [75, 4],
   '76-4': [75, 5],
   '76-5': [75, 6],
   '76-6': [75, 7],
   '76-7': [75, 8],
   '76-8': [75, 9],
   '76-9': [75, 10],
   '76-10': [75, 11],
   '76-11': [75, 12],
   '76-12': [75, 13],
   '77-1': [76, 2],
   '77-2': [76, 3],
   '77-3': [76, 4],
   '77-4': [76, 5],
   '77-5': [76, 6],
   '77-6': [76, 7],
   '77-7': [76, 8],
   '77-8': [76, 9],
   '77-9': [76, 10],
   '77-10': [76, 11],
   '77-11': [76, 12],
   '77-12': [76, 13],
   '77-13': [76, 14],
   '77-14': [76, 15],
   '77-15': [76, 16],
   '77-16': [76, 17],
   '77-17': [76, 18],
   '77-18': [76, 19],
   '77-19': [76, 20],
   '77-20': [76, 21],
   '78-1': [77, 1],
   '78-2': [77, 2],
   '78-3': [77, 3],
   '78-4': [77, 4],
   '78-5': [77, 5],
   '78-6': [77, 6],
   '78-7': [77, 7],
   '78-8': [77, 8],
   '78-9': [77, 9],
   '78-10': [77, 10],
   '78-11': [77, 11],
   '78-12': [77, 12],
   '78-13': [77, 13],
   '78-14': [77, 14],
   '78-15': [77, 15],
   '78-16': [77, 16],
   '78-17': [77, 17],
   '78-18': [77, 18],
   '78-19': [77, 19],
   '78-20': [77, 20],
   '78-21': [77, 21],
   '78-22': [77, 22],
   '78-23': [77, 23],
   '78-24': [77, 24],
   '78-25': [77, 25],
   '78-26': [77, 26],
   '78-27': [77, 27],
   '78-28': [77, 28],
   '78-29': [77, 29],
   '78-30': [77, 30],
   '78-31': [77, 31],
   '78-32': [77, 32],
   '78-33': [77, 33],
   '78-34': [77, 34],
   '78-35': [77, 35],
   '78-36': [77, 36],
   '78-37': [77, 37],
   '78-38': [77, 38],
   '78-39': [77, 39],
   '78-40': [77, 40],
   '78-41': [77, 41],
   '78-42': [77, 42],
   '78-43': [77, 43],
   '78-44': [77, 44],
   '78-45': [77, 45],
   '78-46': [77, 46],
   '78-47': [77, 47],
   '78-48': [77, 48],
   '78-49': [77, 49],
   '78-50': [77, 50],
   '78-51': [77, 51],
   '78-52': [77, 52],
   '78-53': [77, 53],
   '78-54': [77, 54],
   '78-55': [77, 55],
   '78-56': [77, 56],
   '78-57': [77, 57],
   '78-58': [77, 58],
   '78-59': [77, 59],
   '78-60': [77, 60],
   '78-61': [77, 61],
   '78-62': [77, 62],
   '78-63': [77, 63],
   '78-64': [77, 64],
   '78-65': [77, 65],
   '78-66': [77, 66],
   '78-67': [77, 67],
   '78-68': [77, 68],
   '78-69': [77, 69],
   '78-70': [77, 70],
   '78-71': [77, 71],
   '78-72': [77, 72],
```

If you want the data in another format or you want the programs I used to compile the list, feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 1):

Rest of the table:

```
   '79-1': [78, 1],
   '79-2': [78, 2],
   '79-3': [78, 3],
   '79-4': [78, 4],
   '79-5': [78, 5],
   '79-6': [78, 6],
   '79-7': [78, 7],
   '79-8': [78, 8],
   '79-9': [78, 9],
   '79-10': [78, 10],
   '79-11': [78, 11],
   '79-12': [78, 12],
   '79-13': [78, 13],
   '80-1': [79, 2],
   '80-2': [79, 3],
   '80-3': [79, 4],
   '80-4': [79, 5],
   '80-5': [79, 6],
   '80-6': [79, 7],
   '80-7': [79, 8],
   '80-8': [79, 9],
   '80-9': [79, 10],
   '80-10': [79, 11],
   '80-11': [79, 12],
   '80-12': [79, 13],
   '80-13': [79, 14],
   '80-14': [79, 15],
   '80-15': [79, 16],
   '80-16': [79, 17],
   '80-17': [79, 18],
   '80-18': [79, 19],
   '80-19': [79, 20],
   '81-1': [80, 2],
   '81-2': [80, 3],
   '81-3': [80, 4],
   '81-4': [80, 5],
   '81-5': [80, 6],
   '81-6': [80, 7],
   '81-7': [80, 8],
   '81-8': [80, 9],
   '81-9': [80, 10],
   '81-10': [80, 11],
   '81-11': [80, 12],
   '81-12': [80, 13],
   '81-13': [80, 14],
   '81-14': [80, 15],
   '81-15': [80, 16],
   '81-16': [80, 17],
   '82-1': [81, 1],
   '82-2': [81, 2],
   '82-3': [81, 3],
   '82-4': [81, 4],
   '82-5': [81, 5],
   '82-6': [81, 6],
   '82-7': [81, 7],
   '82-8': [81, 8],
   '83-1': [82, 2],
   '83-2': [82, 3],
   '83-3': [82, 4],
   '83-4': [82, 5],
   '83-5': [82, 6],
   '83-6': [82, 7],
   '83-7': [82, 8],
   '83-8': [82, 9],
   '83-9': [82, 10],
   '83-10': [82, 11],
   '83-11': [82, 12],
   '83-12': [82, 13],
   '83-13': [82, 14],
   '83-14': [82, 15],
   '83-15': [82, 16],
   '83-16': [82, 17],
   '83-17': [82, 18],
   '83-18': [82, 19],
   '84-1': [83, 2],
   '84-2': [83, 3],
   '84-3': [83, 4],
   '84-4': [83, 5],
   '84-5': [83, 6],
   '84-6': [83, 7],
   '84-7': [83, 8],
   '84-8': [83, 9],
   '84-9': [83, 10],
   '84-10': [83, 11],
   '84-11': [83, 12],
   '84-12': [83, 13],
   '85-1': [84, 2],
   '85-2': [84, 3],
   '85-3': [84, 4],
   '85-4': [84, 5],
   '85-5': [84, 6],
   '85-6': [84, 7],
   '85-7': [84, 8],
   '85-8': [84, 9],
   '85-9': [84, 10],
   '85-10': [84, 11],
   '85-11': [84, 12],
   '85-12': [84, 13],
   '85-13': [84, 14],
   '86-1': [85, 1],
   '86-2': [85, 2],
   '86-3': [85, 3],
   '86-4': [85, 4],
   '86-5': [85, 5],
   '86-6': [85, 6],
   '86-7': [85, 7],
   '86-8': [85, 8],
   '86-9': [85, 9],
   '86-10': [85, 10],
   '86-11': [85, 11],
   '86-12': [85, 12],
   '86-13': [85, 13],
   '86-14': [85, 14],
   '86-15': [85, 15],
   '86-16': [85, 16],
   '86-17': [85, 17],
   '87-1': [86, 1],
   '87-2': [86, 2],
   '87-3': [86, 3],
   '87-4': [86, 4],
   '87-5': [86, 5],
   '87-6': [86, 6],
   '87-7': [86, 7],
   '88-1': [87, 2],
   '88-2': [87, 3],
   '88-3': [87, 4],
   '88-4': [87, 5],
   '88-5': [87, 6],
   '88-6': [87, 7],
   '88-7': [87, 8],
   '88-8': [87, 9],
   '88-9': [87, 10],
   '88-10': [87, 11],
   '88-11': [87, 12],
   '88-12': [87, 13],
   '88-13': [87, 14],
   '88-14': [87, 15],
   '88-15': [87, 16],
   '88-16': [87, 17],
   '88-17': [87, 18],
   '88-18': [87, 19],
   '89-1': [88, 2],
   '89-2': [88, 3],
   '89-3': [88, 4],
   '89-4': [88, 5],
   '89-5': [88, 6],
   '89-6': [88, 7],
   '89-7': [88, 8],
   '89-8': [88, 9],
   '89-9': [88, 10],
   '89-10': [88, 11],
   '89-11': [88, 12],
   '89-12': [88, 13],
   '89-13': [88, 14],
   '89-14': [88, 15],
   '89-15': [88, 16],
   '89-16': [88, 17],
   '89-17': [88, 18],
   '89-18': [88, 19],
   '89-19': [88, 20],
   '89-20': [88, 21],
   '89-21': [88, 22],
   '89-22': [88, 23],
   '89-23': [88, 24],
   '89-24': [88, 25],
   '89-25': [88, 26],
   '89-26': [88, 27],
   '89-27': [88, 28],
   '89-28': [88, 29],
   '89-29': [88, 30],
   '89-30': [88, 31],
   '89-31': [88, 32],
   '89-32': [88, 33],
   '89-33': [88, 34],
   '89-34': [88, 35],
   '89-35': [88, 36],
   '89-36': [88, 37],
   '89-37': [88, 38],
   '89-38': [88, 39],
   '89-39': [88, 40],
   '89-40': [88, 41],
   '89-41': [88, 42],
   '89-42': [88, 43],
   '89-43': [88, 44],
   '89-44': [88, 45],
   '89-45': [88, 46],
   '89-46': [88, 47],
   '89-47': [88, 48],
   '89-48': [88, 49],
   '89-49': [88, 50],
   '89-50': [88, 51],
   '89-51': [88, 52],
   '89-52': [88, 53],
   '90-1': [89, 1],
   '90-2': [89, 2],
   '90-3': [89, 3],
   '90-4': [89, 4],
   '90-5': [89, 5],
   '90-6': [89, 6],
   '90-7': [89, 7],
   '90-8': [89, 8],
   '90-9': [89, 9],
   '90-10': [89, 10],
   '90-11': [89, 11],
   '90-12': [89, 12],
   '90-13': [89, 13],
   '90-14': [89, 14],
   '90-15': [89, 15],
   '90-16': [89, 16],
   '90-17': [89, 17],
   '91-1': [90, 1],
   '91-2': [90, 2],
   '91-3': [90, 3],
   '91-4': [90, 4],
   '91-5': [90, 5],
   '91-6': [90, 6],
   '91-7': [90, 7],
   '91-8': [90, 8],
   '91-9': [90, 9],
   '91-10': [90, 10],
   '91-11': [90, 11],
   '91-12': [90, 12],
   '91-13': [90, 13],
   '91-14': [90, 14],
   '91-15': [90, 15],
   '91-16': [90, 16],
   '92-1': [91, 2],
   '92-2': [91, 3],
   '92-3': [91, 4],
   '92-4': [91, 5],
   '92-5': [91, 6],
   '92-6': [91, 7],
   '92-7': [91, 8],
   '92-8': [91, 9],
   '92-9': [91, 10],
   '92-10': [91, 11],
   '92-11': [91, 12],
   '92-12': [91, 13],
   '92-13': [91, 14],
   '92-14': [91, 15],
   '92-15': [91, 16],
   '93-1': [92, 1],
   '93-2': [92, 2],
   '93-3': [92, 3],
   '93-4': [92, 4],
   '93-5': [92, 5],
   '94-1': [93, 1],
   '94-2': [93, 2],
   '94-3': [93, 3],
   '94-4': [93, 4],
   '94-5': [93, 5],
   '94-6': [93, 6],
   '94-7': [93, 7],
   '94-8': [93, 8],
   '94-9': [93, 9],
   '94-10': [93, 10],
   '94-11': [93, 11],
   '94-12': [93, 12],
   '94-13': [93, 13],
   '94-14': [93, 14],
   '94-15': [93, 15],
   '94-16': [93, 16],
   '94-17': [93, 17],
   '94-18': [93, 18],
   '94-19': [93, 19],
   '94-20': [93, 20],
   '94-21': [93, 21],
   '94-22': [93, 22],
   '94-23': [93, 23],
   '95-1': [94, 1],
   '95-2': [94, 2],
   '95-3': [94, 3],
   '95-4': [94, 4],
   '95-5': [94, 5],
   '95-6': [94, 6],
   '95-7': [94, 7],
   '95-8': [94, 8],
   '95-9': [94, 9],
   '95-10': [94, 10],
   '95-11': [94, 11],
   '96-1': [95, 1],
   '96-2': [95, 2],
   '96-3': [95, 3],
   '96-4': [95, 4],
   '96-5': [95, 5],
   '96-6': [95, 6],
   '96-7': [95, 7],
   '96-8': [95, 8],
   '96-9': [95, 9],
   '96-10': [95, 10],
   '96-11': [95, 11],
   '96-12': [95, 12],
   '96-13': [95, 13],
   '97-1': [96, 1],
   '97-2': [96, 2],
   '97-3': [96, 3],
   '97-4': [96, 4],
   '97-5': [96, 5],
   '97-6': [96, 6],
   '97-7': [96, 7],
   '97-8': [96, 8],
   '97-9': [96, 9],
   '97-10': [96, 10],
   '97-11': [96, 11],
   '97-12': [96, 12],
   '98-1': [97, 1],
   '98-2': [97, 2],
   '98-3': [97, 3],
   '98-4': [97, 4],
   '98-5': [97, 5],
   '98-6': [97, 6],
   '98-7': [97, 7],
   '98-8': [97, 8],
   '98-9': [97, 9],
   '99-1': [98, 1],
   '99-2': [98, 2],
   '99-3': [98, 3],
   '99-4': [98, 4],
   '99-5': [98, 5],
   '99-6': [98, 6],
   '99-7': [98, 7],
   '99-8': [98, 8],
   '99-9': [98, 9],
   '100-1': [99, 1],
   '100-2': [99, 2],
   '100-3': [99, 3],
   '100-4': [99, 4],
   '100-5': [99, 5],
   '101-1': [100, 1],
   '101-2': [100, 2],
   '101-3': [100, 3],
   '101-4': [100, 4],
   '101-5': [100, 5],
   '101-6': [100, 6],
   '101-7': [100, 7],
   '101-8': [100, 8],
   '102-1': [101, 2],
   '102-2': [101, 3],
   '102-3': [101, 4],
   '102-4': [101, 5],
   '102-5': [101, 6],
   '102-6': [101, 7],
   '102-7': [101, 8],
   '102-8': [101, 9],
   '102-9': [101, 10],
   '102-10': [101, 11],
   '102-11': [101, 12],
   '102-12': [101, 13],
   '102-13': [101, 14],
   '102-14': [101, 15],
   '102-15': [101, 16],
   '102-16': [101, 17],
   '102-17': [101, 18],
   '102-18': [101, 19],
   '102-19': [101, 20],
   '102-20': [101, 21],
   '102-21': [101, 22],
   '102-22': [101, 23],
   '102-23': [101, 24],
   '102-24': [101, 25],
   '102-25': [101, 26],
   '102-26': [101, 27],
   '102-27': [101, 28],
   '102-28': [101, 29],
   '103-1': [102, 1],
   '103-2': [102, 2],
   '103-3': [102, 3],
   '103-4': [102, 4],
   '103-5': [102, 5],
   '103-6': [102, 6],
   '103-7': [102, 7],
   '103-8': [102, 8],
   '103-9': [102, 9],
   '103-10': [102, 10],
   '103-11': [102, 11],
   '103-12': [102, 12],
   '103-13': [102, 13],
   '103-14': [102, 14],
   '103-15': [102, 15],
   '103-16': [102, 16],
   '103-17': [102, 17],
   '103-18': [102, 18],
   '103-19': [102, 19],
   '103-20': [102, 20],
   '103-21': [102, 21],
   '103-22': [102, 22],
   '104-1': [103, 1],
   '104-2': [103, 2],
   '104-3': [103, 3],
   '104-4': [103, 4],
   '104-5': [103, 5],
   '104-6': [103, 6],
   '104-7': [103, 7],
   '104-8': [103, 8],
   '104-9': [103, 9],
   '104-10': [103, 10],
   '104-11': [103, 11],
   '104-12': [103, 12],
   '104-13': [103, 13],
   '104-14': [103, 14],
   '104-15': [103, 15],
   '104-16': [103, 16],
   '104-17': [103, 17],
   '104-18': [103, 18],
   '104-19': [103, 19],
   '104-20': [103, 20],
   '104-21': [103, 21],
   '104-22': [103, 22],
   '104-23': [103, 23],
   '104-24': [103, 24],
   '104-25': [103, 25],
   '104-26': [103, 26],
   '104-27': [103, 27],
   '104-28': [103, 28],
   '104-29': [103, 29],
   '104-30': [103, 30],
   '104-31': [103, 31],
   '104-32': [103, 32],
   '104-33': [103, 33],
   '104-34': [103, 34],
   '104-35': [103, 35],
   '105-1': [104, 1],
   '105-2': [104, 2],
   '105-3': [104, 3],
   '105-4': [104, 4],
   '105-5': [104, 5],
   '105-6': [104, 6],
   '105-7': [104, 7],
   '105-8': [104, 8],
   '105-9': [104, 9],
   '105-10': [104, 10],
   '105-11': [104, 11],
   '105-12': [104, 12],
   '105-13': [104, 13],
   '105-14': [104, 14],
   '105-15': [104, 15],
   '105-16': [104, 16],
   '105-17': [104, 17],
   '105-18': [104, 18],
   '105-19': [104, 19],
   '105-20': [104, 20],
   '105-21': [104, 21],
   '105-22': [104, 22],
   '105-23': [104, 23],
   '105-24': [104, 24],
   '105-25': [104, 25],
   '105-26': [104, 26],
   '105-27': [104, 27],
   '105-28': [104, 28],
   '105-29': [104, 29],
   '105-30': [104, 30],
   '105-31': [104, 31],
   '105-32': [104, 32],
   '105-33': [104, 33],
   '105-34': [104, 34],
   '105-35': [104, 35],
   '105-36': [104, 36],
   '105-37': [104, 37],
   '105-38': [104, 38],
   '105-39': [104, 39],
   '105-40': [104, 40],
   '105-41': [104, 41],
   '105-42': [104, 42],
   '105-43': [104, 43],
   '105-44': [104, 44],
   '105-45': [104, 45],
   '106-1': [105, 1],
   '106-2': [105, 2],
   '106-3': [105, 3],
   '106-4': [105, 4],
   '106-5': [105, 5],
   '106-6': [105, 6],
   '106-7': [105, 7],
   '106-8': [105, 8],
   '106-9': [105, 9],
   '106-10': [105, 10],
   '106-11': [105, 11],
   '106-12': [105, 12],
   '106-13': [105, 13],
   '106-14': [105, 14],
   '106-15': [105, 15],
   '106-16': [105, 16],
   '106-17': [105, 17],
   '106-18': [105, 18],
   '106-19': [105, 19],
   '106-20': [105, 20],
   '106-21': [105, 21],
   '106-22': [105, 22],
   '106-23': [105, 23],
   '106-24': [105, 24],
   '106-25': [105, 25],
   '106-26': [105, 26],
   '106-27': [105, 27],
   '106-28': [105, 28],
   '106-29': [105, 29],
   '106-30': [105, 30],
   '106-31': [105, 31],
   '106-32': [105, 32],
   '106-33': [105, 33],
   '106-34': [105, 34],
   '106-35': [105, 35],
   '106-36': [105, 36],
   '106-37': [105, 37],
   '106-38': [105, 38],
   '106-39': [105, 39],
   '106-40': [105, 40],
   '106-41': [105, 41],
   '106-42': [105, 42],
   '106-43': [105, 43],
   '106-44': [105, 44],
   '106-45': [105, 45],
   '106-46': [105, 46],
   '106-47': [105, 47],
   '106-48': [105, 48],
   '107-1': [106, 1],
   '107-2': [106, 2],
   '107-3': [106, 3],
   '107-4': [106, 4],
   '107-5': [106, 5],
   '107-6': [106, 6],
   '107-7': [106, 7],
   '107-8': [106, 8],
   '107-9': [106, 9],
   '107-10': [106, 10],
   '107-11': [106, 11],
   '107-12': [106, 12],
   '107-13': [106, 13],
   '107-14': [106, 14],
   '107-15': [106, 15],
   '107-16': [106, 16],
   '107-17': [106, 17],
   '107-18': [106, 18],
   '107-19': [106, 19],
   '107-20': [106, 20],
   '107-21': [106, 21],
   '107-22': [106, 22],
   '107-23': [106, 23],
   '107-24': [106, 24],
   '107-25': [106, 25],
   '107-26': [106, 26],
   '107-27': [106, 27],
   '107-28': [106, 28],
   '107-29': [106, 29],
   '107-30': [106, 30],
   '107-31': [106, 31],
   '107-32': [106, 32],
   '107-33': [106, 33],
   '107-34': [106, 34],
   '107-35': [106, 35],
   '107-36': [106, 36],
   '107-37': [106, 37],
   '107-38': [106, 38],
   '107-39': [106, 39],
   '107-40': [106, 40],
   '107-41': [106, 41],
   '107-42': [106, 42],
   '107-43': [106, 43],
   '108-1': [107, 2],
   '108-2': [107, 3],
   '108-3': [107, 4],
   '108-4': [107, 5],
   '108-5': [107, 6],
   '108-6': [107, 7],
   '108-7': [107, 8],
   '108-8': [107, 9],
   '108-9': [107, 10],
   '108-10': [107, 11],
   '108-11': [107, 12],
   '108-12': [107, 13],
   '108-13': [107, 14],
   '109-1': [108, 1],
   '109-2': [108, 2],
   '109-3': [108, 3],
   '109-4': [108, 4],
   '109-5': [108, 5],
   '109-6': [108, 6],
   '109-7': [108, 7],
   '109-8': [108, 8],
   '109-9': [108, 9],
   '109-10': [108, 10],
   '109-11': [108, 11],
   '109-12': [108, 12],
   '109-13': [108, 13],
   '109-14': [108, 14],
   '109-15': [108, 15],
   '109-16': [108, 16],
   '109-17': [108, 17],
   '109-18': [108, 18],
   '109-19': [108, 19],
   '109-20': [108, 20],
   '109-21': [108, 21],
   '109-22': [108, 22],
   '109-23': [108, 23],
   '109-24': [108, 24],
   '109-25': [108, 25],
   '109-26': [108, 26],
   '109-27': [108, 27],
   '109-28': [108, 28],
   '109-29': [108, 29],
   '109-30': [108, 30],
   '109-31': [108, 31],
   '110-1': [109, 1],
   '110-2': [109, 2],
   '110-3': [109, 3],
   '110-4': [109, 4],
   '110-5': [109, 5],
   '110-6': [109, 6],
   '110-7': [109, 7],
   '111-1': [110, 1],
   '111-2': [110, 2],
   '111-3': [110, 3],
   '111-4': [110, 4],
   '111-5': [110, 5],
   '111-6': [110, 6],
   '111-7': [110, 7],
   '111-8': [110, 8],
   '111-9': [110, 9],
   '111-10': [110, 10],
   '112-1': [111, 1],
   '112-2': [111, 2],
   '112-3': [111, 3],
   '112-4': [111, 4],
   '112-5': [111, 5],
   '112-6': [111, 6],
   '112-7': [111, 7],
   '112-8': [111, 8],
   '112-9': [111, 9],
   '112-10': [111, 10],
   '113-1': [112, 1],
   '113-2': [112, 2],
   '113-3': [112, 3],
   '113-4': [112, 4],
   '113-5': [112, 5],
   '113-6': [112, 6],
   '113-7': [112, 7],
   '113-8': [112, 8],
   '113-9': [112, 9],
   '114-1': [113, 1],
   '114-2': [113, 2],
   '114-3': [113, 3],
   '114-4': [113, 4],
   '114-5': [113, 5],
   '114-6': [113, 6],
   '114-7': [113, 7],
   '114-8': [113, 8],
   '115-1': [113, 9],
   '115-2': [113, 10],
   '115-3': [113, 11],
   '115-4': [113, 12],
   '115-5': [113, 13],
   '115-6': [113, 14],
   '115-7': [113, 15],
   '115-8': [113, 16],
   '115-9': [113, 17],
   '115-10': [113, 18],
   '115-11': [113, 19],
   '115-12': [113, 20],
   '115-13': [113, 21],
   '115-14': [113, 22],
   '115-15': [113, 23],
   '115-16': [113, 24],
   '115-17': [113, 25],
   '115-18': [113, 26],
   '116-1': [114, 1],
   '116-2': [114, 2],
   '116-3': [114, 3],
   '116-4': [114, 4],
   '116-5': [114, 5],
   '116-6': [114, 6],
   '116-7': [114, 7],
   '116-8': [114, 8],
   '116-9': [114, 9],
   '116-10': [115, 1],
   '116-11': [115, 2],
   '116-12': [115, 3],
   '116-13': [115, 4],
   '116-14': [115, 5],
   '116-15': [115, 6],
   '116-16': [115, 7],
   '116-17': [115, 8],
   '116-18': [115, 9],
   '116-19': [115, 10],
   '117-1': [116, 1],
   '117-2': [116, 2],
   '118-1': [117, 1],
   '118-2': [117, 2],
   '118-3': [117, 3],
   '118-4': [117, 4],
   '118-5': [117, 5],
   '118-6': [117, 6],
   '118-7': [117, 7],
   '118-8': [117, 8],
   '118-9': [117, 9],
   '118-10': [117, 10],
   '118-11': [117, 11],
   '118-12': [117, 12],
   '118-13': [117, 13],
   '118-14': [117, 14],
   '118-15': [117, 15],
   '118-16': [117, 16],
   '118-17': [117, 17],
   '118-18': [117, 18],
   '118-19': [117, 19],
   '118-20': [117, 20],
   '118-21': [117, 21],
   '118-22': [117, 22],
   '118-23': [117, 23],
   '118-24': [117, 24],
   '118-25': [117, 25],
   '118-26': [117, 26],
   '118-27': [117, 27],
   '118-28': [117, 28],
   '118-29': [117, 29],
   '119-1': [118, 1],
   '119-2': [118, 2],
   '119-3': [118, 3],
   '119-4': [118, 4],
   '119-5': [118, 5],
   '119-6': [118, 6],
   '119-7': [118, 7],
   '119-8': [118, 8],
   '119-9': [118, 9],
   '119-10': [118, 10],
   '119-11': [118, 11],
   '119-12': [118, 12],
   '119-13': [118, 13],
   '119-14': [118, 14],
   '119-15': [118, 15],
   '119-16': [118, 16],
   '119-17': [118, 17],
   '119-18': [118, 18],
   '119-19': [118, 19],
   '119-20': [118, 20],
   '119-21': [118, 21],
   '119-22': [118, 22],
   '119-23': [118, 23],
   '119-24': [118, 24],
   '119-25': [118, 25],
   '119-26': [118, 26],
   '119-27': [118, 27],
   '119-28': [118, 28],
   '119-29': [118, 29],
   '119-30': [118, 30],
   '119-31': [118, 31],
   '119-32': [118, 32],
   '119-33': [118, 33],
   '119-34': [118, 34],
   '119-35': [118, 35],
   '119-36': [118, 36],
   '119-37': [118, 37],
   '119-38': [118, 38],
   '119-39': [118, 39],
   '119-40': [118, 40],
   '119-41': [118, 41],
   '119-42': [118, 42],
   '119-43': [118, 43],
   '119-44': [118, 44],
   '119-45': [118, 45],
   '119-46': [118, 46],
   '119-47': [118, 47],
   '119-48': [118, 48],
   '119-49': [118, 49],
   '119-50': [118, 50],
   '119-51': [118, 51],
   '119-52': [118, 52],
   '119-53': [118, 53],
   '119-54': [118, 54],
   '119-55': [118, 55],
   '119-56': [118, 56],
   '119-57': [118, 57],
   '119-58': [118, 58],
   '119-59': [118, 59],
   '119-60': [118, 60],
   '119-61': [118, 61],
   '119-62': [118, 62],
   '119-63': [118, 63],
   '119-64': [118, 64],
   '119-65': [118, 65],
   '119-66': [118, 66],
   '119-67': [118, 67],
   '119-68': [118, 68],
   '119-69': [118, 69],
   '119-70': [118, 70],
   '119-71': [118, 71],
   '119-72': [118, 72],
   '119-73': [118, 73],
   '119-74': [118, 74],
   '119-75': [118, 75],
   '119-76': [118, 76],
   '119-77': [118, 77],
   '119-78': [118, 78],
   '119-79': [118, 79],
   '119-80': [118, 80],
   '119-81': [118, 81],
   '119-82': [118, 82],
   '119-83': [118, 83],
   '119-84': [118, 84],
   '119-85': [118, 85],
   '119-86': [118, 86],
   '119-87': [118, 87],
   '119-88': [118, 88],
   '119-89': [118, 89],
   '119-90': [118, 90],
   '119-91': [118, 91],
   '119-92': [118, 92],
   '119-93': [118, 93],
   '119-94': [118, 94],
   '119-95': [118, 95],
   '119-96': [118, 96],
   '119-97': [118, 97],
   '119-98': [118, 98],
   '119-99': [118, 99],
   '119-100': [118, 100],
   '119-101': [118, 101],
   '119-102': [118, 102],
   '119-103': [118, 103],
   '119-104': [118, 104],
   '119-105': [118, 105],
   '119-106': [118, 106],
   '119-107': [118, 107],
   '119-108': [118, 108],
   '119-109': [118, 109],
   '119-110': [118, 110],
   '119-111': [118, 111],
   '119-112': [118, 112],
   '119-113': [118, 113],
   '119-114': [118, 114],
   '119-115': [118, 115],
   '119-116': [118, 116],
   '119-117': [118, 117],
   '119-118': [118, 118],
   '119-119': [118, 119],
   '119-120': [118, 120],
   '119-121': [118, 121],
   '119-122': [118, 122],
   '119-123': [118, 123],
   '119-124': [118, 124],
   '119-125': [118, 125],
   '119-126': [118, 126],
   '119-127': [118, 127],
   '119-128': [118, 128],
   '119-129': [118, 129],
   '119-130': [118, 130],
   '119-131': [118, 131],
   '119-132': [118, 132],
   '119-133': [118, 133],
   '119-134': [118, 134],
   '119-135': [118, 135],
   '119-136': [118, 136],
   '119-137': [118, 137],
   '119-138': [118, 138],
   '119-139': [118, 139],
   '119-140': [118, 140],
   '119-141': [118, 141],
   '119-142': [118, 142],
   '119-143': [118, 143],
   '119-144': [118, 144],
   '119-145': [118, 145],
   '119-146': [118, 146],
   '119-147': [118, 147],
   '119-148': [118, 148],
   '119-149': [118, 149],
   '119-150': [118, 150],
   '119-151': [118, 151],
   '119-152': [118, 152],
   '119-153': [118, 153],
   '119-154': [118, 154],
   '119-155': [118, 155],
   '119-156': [118, 156],
   '119-157': [118, 157],
   '119-158': [118, 158],
   '119-159': [118, 159],
   '119-160': [118, 160],
   '119-161': [118, 161],
   '119-162': [118, 162],
   '119-163': [118, 163],
   '119-164': [118, 164],
   '119-165': [118, 165],
   '119-166': [118, 166],
   '119-167': [118, 167],
   '119-168': [118, 168],
   '119-169': [118, 169],
   '119-170': [118, 170],
   '119-171': [118, 171],
   '119-172': [118, 172],
   '119-173': [118, 173],
   '119-174': [118, 174],
   '119-175': [118, 175],
   '119-176': [118, 176],
   '120-1': [119, 1],
   '120-2': [119, 2],
   '120-3': [119, 3],
   '120-4': [119, 4],
   '120-5': [119, 5],
   '120-6': [119, 6],
   '120-7': [119, 7],
   '121-1': [120, 1],
   '121-2': [120, 2],
   '121-3': [120, 3],
   '121-4': [120, 4],
   '121-5': [120, 5],
   '121-6': [120, 6],
   '121-7': [120, 7],
   '121-8': [120, 8],
   '122-1': [121, 1],
   '122-2': [121, 2],
   '122-3': [121, 3],
   '122-4': [121, 4],
   '122-5': [121, 5],
   '122-6': [121, 6],
   '122-7': [121, 7],
   '122-8': [121, 8],
   '122-9': [121, 9],
   '123-1': [122, 1],
   '123-2': [122, 2],
   '123-3': [122, 3],
   '123-4': [122, 4],
   '124-1': [123, 1],
   '124-2': [123, 2],
   '124-3': [123, 3],
   '124-4': [123, 4],
   '124-5': [123, 5],
   '124-6': [123, 6],
   '124-7': [123, 7],
   '124-8': [123, 8],
   '125-1': [124, 1],
   '125-2': [124, 2],
   '125-3': [124, 3],
   '125-4': [124, 4],
   '125-5': [124, 5],
   '126-1': [125, 1],
   '126-2': [125, 2],
   '126-3': [125, 3],
   '126-4': [125, 4],
   '126-5': [125, 5],
   '126-6': [125, 6],
   '127-1': [126, 1],
   '127-2': [126, 2],
   '127-3': [126, 3],
   '127-4': [126, 4],
   '127-5': [126, 5],
   '128-1': [127, 1],
   '128-2': [127, 2],
   '128-3': [127, 3],
   '128-4': [127, 4],
   '128-5': [127, 5],
   '128-6': [127, 6],
   '129-1': [128, 1],
   '129-2': [128, 2],
   '129-3': [128, 3],
   '129-4': [128, 4],
   '129-5': [128, 5],
   '129-6': [128, 6],
   '129-7': [128, 7],
   '129-8': [128, 8],
   '130-1': [129, 1],
   '130-2': [129, 2],
   '130-3': [129, 3],
   '130-4': [129, 4],
   '130-5': [129, 5],
   '130-6': [129, 6],
   '130-7': [129, 7],
   '130-8': [129, 8],
   '131-1': [130, 1],
   '131-2': [130, 2],
   '131-3': [130, 3],
   '132-1': [131, 1],
   '132-2': [131, 2],
   '132-3': [131, 3],
   '132-4': [131, 4],
   '132-5': [131, 5],
   '132-6': [131, 6],
   '132-7': [131, 7],
   '132-8': [131, 8],
   '132-9': [131, 9],
   '132-10': [131, 10],
   '132-11': [131, 11],
   '132-12': [131, 12],
   '132-13': [131, 13],
   '132-14': [131, 14],
   '132-15': [131, 15],
   '132-16': [131, 16],
   '132-17': [131, 17],
   '132-18': [131, 18],
   '133-1': [132, 1],
   '133-2': [132, 2],
   '133-3': [132, 3],
   '134-1': [133, 1],
   '134-2': [133, 2],
   '134-3': [133, 3],
   '135-1': [134, 1],
   '135-2': [134, 2],
   '135-3': [134, 3],
   '135-4': [134, 4],
   '135-5': [134, 5],
   '135-6': [134, 6],
   '135-7': [134, 7],
   '135-8': [134, 8],
   '135-9': [134, 9],
   '135-10': [134, 10],
   '135-11': [134, 11],
   '135-12': [134, 12],
   '135-13': [134, 13],
   '135-14': [134, 14],
   '135-15': [134, 15],
   '135-16': [134, 16],
   '135-17': [134, 17],
   '135-18': [134, 18],
   '135-19': [134, 19],
   '135-20': [134, 20],
   '135-21': [134, 21],
   '136-1': [135, 1],
   '136-2': [135, 2],
   '136-3': [135, 3],
   '136-4': [135, 4],
   '136-5': [135, 5],
   '136-6': [135, 6],
   '136-7': [135, 7],
   '136-8': [135, 8],
   '136-9': [135, 9],
   '136-10': [135, 10],
   '136-11': [135, 11],
   '136-12': [135, 12],
   '136-13': [135, 13],
   '136-14': [135, 14],
   '136-15': [135, 15],
   '136-16': [135, 16],
   '136-17': [135, 17],
   '136-18': [135, 18],
   '136-19': [135, 19],
   '136-20': [135, 20],
   '136-21': [135, 21],
   '136-22': [135, 22],
   '136-23': [135, 23],
   '136-24': [135, 24],
   '136-25': [135, 25],
   '136-26': [135, 26],
   '137-1': [136, 1],
   '137-2': [136, 2],
   '137-3': [136, 3],
   '137-4': [136, 4],
   '137-5': [136, 5],
   '137-6': [136, 6],
   '137-7': [136, 7],
   '137-8': [136, 8],
   '137-9': [136, 9],
   '138-1': [137, 1],
   '138-2': [137, 2],
   '138-3': [137, 3],
   '138-4': [137, 4],
   '138-5': [137, 5],
   '138-6': [137, 6],
   '138-7': [137, 7],
   '138-8': [137, 8],
   '139-1': [138, 1],
   '139-2': [138, 2],
   '139-3': [138, 3],
   '139-4': [138, 4],
   '139-5': [138, 5],
   '139-6': [138, 6],
   '139-7': [138, 7],
   '139-8': [138, 8],
   '139-9': [138, 9],
   '139-10': [138, 10],
   '139-11': [138, 11],
   '139-12': [138, 12],
   '139-13': [138, 13],
   '139-14': [138, 14],
   '139-15': [138, 15],
   '139-16': [138, 16],
   '139-17': [138, 17],
   '139-18': [138, 18],
   '139-19': [138, 19],
   '139-20': [138, 20],
   '139-21': [138, 21],
   '139-22': [138, 22],
   '139-23': [138, 23],
   '139-24': [138, 24],
   '140-1': [139, 2],
   '140-2': [139, 3],
   '140-3': [139, 4],
   '140-4': [139, 5],
   '140-5': [139, 6],
   '140-6': [139, 7],
   '140-7': [139, 8],
   '140-8': [139, 9],
   '140-9': [139, 10],
   '140-10': [139, 11],
   '140-11': [139, 12],
   '140-12': [139, 13],
   '140-13': [139, 14],
   '141-1': [140, 1],
   '141-2': [140, 2],
   '141-3': [140, 3],
   '141-4': [140, 4],
   '141-5': [140, 5],
   '141-6': [140, 6],
   '141-7': [140, 7],
   '141-8': [140, 8],
   '141-9': [140, 9],
   '141-10': [140, 10],
   '142-1': [141, 2],
   '142-2': [141, 3],
   '142-3': [141, 4],
   '142-4': [141, 5],
   '142-5': [141, 6],
   '142-6': [141, 7],
   '142-7': [141, 8],
   '143-1': [142, 1],
   '143-2': [142, 2],
   '143-3': [142, 3],
   '143-4': [142, 4],
   '143-5': [142, 5],
   '143-6': [142, 6],
   '143-7': [142, 7],
   '143-8': [142, 8],
   '143-9': [142, 9],
   '143-10': [142, 10],
   '143-11': [142, 11],
   '143-12': [142, 12],
   '144-1': [143, 1],
   '144-2': [143, 2],
   '144-3': [143, 3],
   '144-4': [143, 4],
   '144-5': [143, 5],
   '144-6': [143, 6],
   '144-7': [143, 7],
   '144-8': [143, 8],
   '144-9': [143, 9],
   '144-10': [143, 10],
   '144-11': [143, 11],
   '144-12': [143, 12],
   '144-13': [143, 13],
   '144-14': [143, 14],
   '144-15': [143, 15],
   '145-1': [144, 1],
   '145-2': [144, 2],
   '145-3': [144, 3],
   '145-4': [144, 4],
   '145-5': [144, 5],
   '145-6': [144, 6],
   '145-7': [144, 7],
   '145-8': [144, 8],
   '145-9': [144, 9],
   '145-10': [144, 10],
   '145-11': [144, 11],
   '145-12': [144, 12],
   '145-13': [144, 13],
   '145-14': [144, 14],
   '145-15': [144, 15],
   '145-16': [144, 16],
   '145-17': [144, 17],
   '145-18': [144, 18],
   '145-19': [144, 19],
   '145-20': [144, 20],
   '145-21': [144, 21],
   '146-1': [145, 1],
   '146-2': [145, 2],
   '146-3': [145, 3],
   '146-4': [145, 4],
   '146-5': [145, 5],
   '146-6': [145, 6],
   '146-7': [145, 7],
   '146-8': [145, 8],
   '146-9': [145, 9],
   '146-10': [145, 10],
   '147-1': [146, 1],
   '147-2': [146, 2],
   '147-3': [146, 3],
   '147-4': [146, 4],
   '147-5': [146, 5],
   '147-6': [146, 6],
   '147-7': [146, 7],
   '147-8': [146, 8],
   '147-9': [146, 9],
   '147-10': [146, 10],
   '147-11': [146, 11],
   '147-12': [147, 1],
   '147-13': [147, 2],
   '147-14': [147, 3],
   '147-15': [147, 4],
   '147-16': [147, 5],
   '147-17': [147, 6],
   '147-18': [147, 7],
   '147-19': [147, 8],
   '147-20': [147, 9],
   '148-1': [148, 1],
   '148-2': [148, 2],
   '148-3': [148, 3],
   '148-4': [148, 4],
   '148-5': [148, 5],
   '148-6': [148, 6],
   '148-7': [148, 7],
   '148-8': [148, 8],
   '148-9': [148, 9],
   '148-10': [148, 10],
   '148-11': [148, 11],
   '148-12': [148, 12],
   '148-13': [148, 13],
   '148-14': [148, 14],
   '149-1': [149, 1],
   '149-2': [149, 2],
   '149-3': [149, 3],
   '149-4': [149, 4],
   '149-5': [149, 5],
   '149-6': [149, 6],
   '149-7': [149, 7],
   '149-8': [149, 8],
   '149-9': [149, 9],
   '150-1': [150, 1],
   '150-2': [150, 2],
   '150-3': [150, 3],
   '150-4': [150, 4],
   '150-5': [150, 5],
   '150-6': [150, 6],
}
```